# Aligning boxed equations in a specific way within subequations and rounding corners

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, subequations, box, empheq

I have the following code which uses code from online sources

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{empheq}


\newsavebox{\mysaveboxM} % M for math
\newsavebox{\mysaveboxT} % T for text

\newcommand*\Garybox[2][Example]{%
    \sbox{\mysaveboxM}{#2}%
    \sbox{\mysaveboxT}{\fcolorbox{black}{white}{#1}}%
    \sbox{\mysaveboxM}{%
        \parbox[b][\ht\mysaveboxM+.5\ht\mysaveboxT+.5\dp\mysaveboxT][b]{\wd\mysaveboxM}{#2}%
    }%
    \sbox{\mysaveboxM}{%
        \fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
            \makebox[\linewidth-10em]{\usebox{\mysaveboxM}}%
        }%
    }%
    \usebox{\mysaveboxM}%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{%
        \makebox[\wd\mysaveboxM][c]{%
            \raisebox{\ht\mysaveboxM-0.5\ht\mysaveboxT+0.5\dp\mysaveboxT-0.5\fboxrule}{\usebox{\mysaveboxT}}%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
            \begin{empheq}[box=\Garybox]{align}
        \sum \mathbf{F} &= \mathbf{0} \label{a} \\
        \sum F_{x} \,\mathbf{i} + \sum F_{y} \,\mathbf{j} + \sum F_{z} \,\mathbf{k} &= 
        \mathbf{0} \label{b} \\
        \sum F_{x} &= 0 \label{c} \\
        \sum F_{y} &= 0 \label{d} \\
        \sum F_{z} &= 0 \label{e}
        \end{empheq}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

and I get the following
[image]

I need to make all corners rounded, and also the equations do not appear to be centered, where I would like each equation to be centered on its line.
I have been trying to modify the code, but I get compilation errors or no changes at all. I would appreciate any and all help on this, and I thank all helpers.

Comment: I can't help with rounding corners, but you have explicitly used `align` and indicated the alignment point in each line with a `&`.  The `amsmath` grouping with each line centered separately is `gather`, but how that works in the `empheq` environment is also unknown to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With tcolorbox p.15 the doc

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%<--- see the dox tcolorbox p.15
  colback=red!5!white,
  colframe=red!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  colbacktitle=red!85!black,
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
  title={#2},#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}[colback=yellow]{Example}%<--- see the dox tcolorbox p.15
  \begin{subequations}
    \begin{gather}
      \sum \mathbf{F} = \mathbf{0} \label{a} \\
      \sum F_{x} \,\mathbf{i} + \sum F_{y} \,\mathbf{j} + \sum F_{z} \,\mathbf{k} = \mathbf{0} \label{b} \\
      \sum F_{x} = 0 \label{c} \\
      \sum F_{y} = 0 \label{d} \\
      \sum F_{z} = 0 \label{e}
    \end{gather}
  \end{subequations}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer, it is very helpful